# Running Arquillian in Equinox

Tags: osgi, equinox, apache-felix, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to run integration tests in an OSGi container, namely the Equinox container embedded in Eclipse, using Arquillian in remote mode.

I followed [the instructions](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBOSGI/Arquillian+Test+Framework) given on the JBoss OSGI site. So I began by provisionning my target platform by adding these artefacts (which I found by browsing the [jboss repository](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#view-repositories;public-jboss~browsestorage)) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-osgi-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <!-- required by arquillian-osgi-bundle -->
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.osgi.jmx</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-osgi-jmx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to validate the bundles, I get unsatisfied imports from jboss-osgi-jmx :

- missing package org.jboss.osgi.spi.capability
- missing package org.jboss.osgi.testing

Apparently, the missing packages belong to these artifacts (once again, found by browsing):

```
<!-- osgi.spi : this one ?-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.osgi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-osgi-spi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
<!-- or that one ?-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.osgi.spi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbosgi-spi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.26</version>
</dependency>

<!-- osgi.testing -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.osgi.testing</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbosgi-testing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

But neither of these artifacts is an OSGI bundle, so I'm stuck with unresolved constraints.

So, my questions are :

- did I screw up my platform configuration ?
- does anybody already succeeded at using Arquillian inside a non-JBoss
  osgi container in remote mode (plain felix would be OK) ?

Answer (score -1):

Try [Pax Exam](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxexam/Pax+Exam) for OSGi testing. You can choose between embedded and remote usage (Native Test Container vs. Forked Test Container).

Pax Exam supports all OSGI 4.2 compliant frameworks. It it regression tested on Equinox, Felix and Knopflerfish.

Comment: I am aware of Pax Exam but I wanted to specifically evaluate Arquillian

Comment: The poster specifically asks about Arquillian.